# <p:commandLink> updates <p:datatable> only after a second click

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, action, jsf-2.2

Basically, I'm trying to fire an action from a `<p:commandLink>` to update a `<p:datatable>` and a `<p:growl>`.

The `<p:growl>` is updated instantly, but the `<p:datatable>` is updated only after a second click.

Here is the XHTML code :

```
<h:body>
<h:form id="form1" > 
 <p:layout id="layout"> 
   <p:layoutUnit id="north" position="north">
      <p:growl id="msg" showDetail="true" />
        <h:column>
          <p:commandButton id="searchdate"
                            value="Rechercher"
                            actionListener="#{dyna.search}"
                            update=":form1:tabexam,:form1:msg"/>
        </h:column>
   </p:layoutUnit>
 <p:layoutUnit position="center"
               resizable="true"
               collapsible="true"
               effect="drop"
               size="300"
               styleClass="heighter">  

      <p:dataTable id="tabexam"
                   paginatorPosition="bottom"
                   var="exam"
                   value="#{dyna.listexam}"
                   widgetVar="examTable"
                   emptyMessage="aucun résultat."
                   filteredValue="#{dyna.filteredexams}"
                   paginator="true"
                   rows="20"
                   rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,40,80"
                   binding="#{dyna.table}">

          <f:facet name="header" >  
               <h:outputText value="Rechercher: "/>  
              <p:inputText id="globalFilter"
                           onkeyup="examTable.filter();" 
                           style="width:200px" /> 
          </f:facet>  
      </p:dataTable>
</p:layoutUnit>      
<p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="false" header="Liste Perso.">
 <ui:repeat  var="list" value="#{userBean.userLists}">
   <center>
     <p:commandLink id="listerlink"
                    title="Afficher la liste"
                    action ="#{dyna.refreshChildren(list.id.tbCode)}"
                    update=":form1:tabexam,:form1:msg">      
       <p:graphicImage id="imglist"  value="/images/Liste_Cold.png"/><br></br>
       <p:outputLabel value="#{list.id.tbCode}" /><br></br>
     </p:commandLink>
   </center>
 </ui:repeat>
</p:layoutUnit>
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

Here is some code from my ManagedBean.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "dyna", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class DynamicDatatable implements java.io.Serializable {
@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    listexam = DAO_Examen.getAllExamens();
    selectedExamen = new Cotation();
    etatExamOptions = createFilterOptions();
    payExamOptions = createFilterOptions2();
    salleOptions = DAO_Salle.getAllSalle(UserBean.user.getUserId());
    refreshChildren("default");

}
public void refreshChildren(String listid) {
    try {
        //config
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Application application = fc.getApplication();
        ExpressionFactory ef = application.getExpressionFactory();
        ELContext elc = fc.getELContext();

        //Table
        table = (DataTable) application.createComponent(DataTable.COMPONENT_TYPE);

        //columns spec.
        ArrayList<ColumnModel> columnmodel = DAO_UserLists.createUserColumnSpec(UserBean.user.getUserId(), "SITE1", listid);

        if (columnmodel != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < columnmodel.size(); i++) {

                if ((columnmodel.get(i) != null) && (columnmodel.get(i).getDbname() != null)) {

                    Column column = (Column) application.createComponent(Column.COMPONENT_TYPE);
                    column.setHeaderText(columnmodel.get(i).getUserListname());
                    column.setWidth("10");
                    column.setId("Col_" + columnmodel.get(i).getHeadername());
                    column.setStyleClass("dispo");
                    column.setSortBy(columnmodel.get(i).getDbname());
                    column.setRendered(columnmodel.get(i).isVisible());
                    table.getChildren().add(column);
}
   }

   FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Terminé avec succes", "la liste " + listid + " est bien chargée");
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }
}
```

API's Version:
JSF 2.2
primefaces 4.0

Comment: does refreshChildren() method execute successfully at first click??

Comment: Yes, the method refreshChildren() does execute at the first click but the update won't occur until the second click.

Comment: It's huge, which part is most important to you ?

Comment: @Papa_Jay -: You can add one attribute `process="tabexam"` in `<p:commandLink>`.

Comment: @Diganta : sure i will try that right away.

Comment: @kark okay, i will post it right away.

Comment: @Diganta : i tried it and it gave me a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: L’ID de composant «form1:tabexam:j_idt31» a déjà été détecté dans la vue" in english : the ID form1:tabexam:j_idt31 already detected in the view.

Comment: I can see a typo on `p:datatable`, please add `"` at the end of `emptyMessage` attribute

Comment: Have you already debugged the backingbean method? Do that and check if it does exactly what you want. As it shows the facesmessage you are adding at the and of the method I guess this is not a update problem.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with `<p:datatable>` binding ?

Comment: Binding an UI component to a bean in a broader scope than the request scope is indeed asking for trouble (components are namely request scoped). Why don't you just use `<p:columns value="#{dyna.culumnmodel}">`?

Comment: i thought about that, i will try that right away.

Comment: I get problems with properties not recognized.

Comment: I'm stuck on this one again, i feel disappointed about this, why can't  my code just run normally, why do i have to click twice, is there any workaround for this @BalusC, please help there is no one above your knowledge here.

Comment: I have the same problem. My action method gets executed but the datatable won't update until i press a commandLink again (any commandLink i have around will do the trick fire the next action and won't update the datatable)...

Comment: I have same problem...in 2019!